# Being transitioned to a new role because company hired a new senior level position, should I be worried?

Tags: transition

I've been working for company X for 1.5 years. I started as a corporate finance manager and previous to that I was an analyst. The company is growing and recently added a new VP corporate finance. I had one direct report who now reports to the new VP. I'm being transitioned to a somewhat new role but with no title change and report to a different VP. Should I be worried that my position is slowly being squeezed out?

Edit: I work for a PE-backed company.

Comment: Not based on what you've written. And if so, so what -- are you incapable of taking up a new role?

Comment: Thanks -- It doesn't hurt to keep eyes and ears open. I've been in restructuring before and found that it's best to keep your head down and continue producing good work. At the same time be very observant of the on going changes and dynamics. Don't react too quickly but plan for your next step just in case.

Answer (score 2):

It is very common for a growing company to hire an analyst, promote that person to a more senior position, and then, hire in a far more experienced person above them. The company may think that they need to hire for where they want to grow to instead of trying to train you on the job. This process is especially true in fields like finance and accounting. They are planning on being significantly larger or they are planning on an IPO or buyout which needs specialized skills in the finance department.

Your position depends on what you can learn from this new VP.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry too much about that. No one works forever in the same role or with the same company for his/her whole career.

Besides, what else can you do ? The boss transfers you to a new team. So, all you can do is to do your best in that new role to prove that you have talent and can work hard to earn great success for the company.

If things get worse later on, then you can re-examine your employment path, but for now, let's see what will happen next.